# Como acentuar em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, acentuação

Estou escrevendo um programa e ele fica dando erro de ascii.
Já coloquei isto na primeira linha e nada:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

A pedido, segue edição explicando o que é now.

now é variável para a datetime e acredito que não possui relação.

A acentuação no console (terminal) está normal. O que não dá certo é porque eu coloquei para escrever em um arquivo .txt e quando coloca para escrever com acento que aparece esse erro.

Fiz o que mgibsonbr pediu e deu tudo ok. Uso OS X.

Então, recapitulando:
- now é uma variável para datetime que não tem nada com a acentuação (acredito);
- O erro de acentuação só aparece quando vou escrever em um arquivo .txt;

Comment: Poderia colocar a parte do código que dá erro?

Comment: O código que desejo colocar acento é este:    
`f.write('- %s/%s/%s às %s:%s -\n' % (now.day, now.month, now.year, now.hour, now.minute))`    
    
E o erro que recebo é este:    
`Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "/Users/gabrielazevedo/Meus Trabalhos/Python/Calculadora de Imposto e Gorjeta.py", line 32, in <module>    
    f.write('- %s/%s/%s às %s:%s -\n' % (now.day, now.month, now.year, now.hour, now.minute))    
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe0' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Edite a sua questão com o código e, se possível, coloque o que é o now. (:

Comment: Pergunta besta, mas você tem certeza que seu arquivo fonte está codificado como UTF-8, certo? Para ter certeza, experimente colocar `x = "á"` na segunda linha do arquivo e `print("ok")` na terceira, se ele **não** imprimir "ok" então provavelmente seu arquivo fonte está com a codificação errada (se você estiver no Windows, provavelmente é `Cp1252`).

Comment: Editei para vocês lerem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você abre um arquivo no Python para escrita usando o *built-in* `open`:

```
with open("arquivo.txt", mode="w") as f:
    f.write("blá")
```

Ele assume que [esse arquivo está na codificação padrão do sistema](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html#files-in-a-typical-platform-specific-encoding) (no Python 2, ele assume que o arquivo é `latin-1`, o que é péssimo). Ou pelo menos é o que diz a documentação, pois seu erro sugere que a *stream* está rejeitando caracteres acima de `0x7F`, de modo que a codificação usada parece ser ASCII.

O Python 3 possui [alguns métodos diferentes de lidar com codificações de caracteres](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html), mas a maneira mais recomendada de se trabalhar com arquivos de texto quando você tem controle total dos mesmos é fornecer uma codificação explícita. Então a escrita deve ocorrer sem problemas:

```
with open("arquivo.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write("blá")
```

Para referência, vou mostrar também o modo de se fazer no Python 2:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("arquivo.txt", "w", "utf-8") as f:
    f.write(u"blá")
```

Naturalmente, você pode escolher outra codificação de caracteres para seu arquivo de saída, se quiser (não precisa ser a mesma do arquivo fonte).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!
Obrigado :)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Por favor, am vez de "em algumas circunstâncias", e encoding ASCII, de uma lida nesse artigo: http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_%28Sem_Desculpas!%29 --(nao se sinta constrangido pelo titulo ) - Apesar da sua resposta funcionar, você está com muito 'achismo" para uma coisa que é deterministica: codificação de text o - e com certeza vai tirar bastante proveito das informações ali.

Comment: @jsbueno Conheço esse artigo. Onde exatamente na minha resposta eu errei? O Python 3, quando você não especifica um *encoding*, deixa você ler e escrever caracteres ASCII (bytes entre `0x00` e `0x7F`) à vontade, e também deixa por exemplo você **ler** um byte acima de `0x80` e **reescrever** esse mesmo byte, sem modificação, em outro arquivo. Pessoalmente, me parece um *default* inseguro (nem todos os *encodings* são compatíveis com ASCII, aqueles usados no Japão por exemplo), mas é o que o Python 3 faz, então achei importante citar. O link de referência explica melhor esse comportamento.

Comment: @jsbueno Reli a documentação, me parece que o Python 3 possui vários modos de operação: *"best effort is acceptable"*, onde o programador sabe que a codificação é compatível com ASCII mas não sabe bem qual é. Nesse caso, ele especifica `latin-1` como `encoding` e a coisa funciona como eu descrevi acima. Outro modo é *"minimize risk of data corruption"*, cenário semelhante, mas com tratamento de erros diferente. Outros são "sempre usar a codificação padrão do sistema", "usar uma codificação explícita", "usar um marcador para auto-identificar a codificação".

Comment: @mgibsonbr - vi umas respostas suas sobre o tema em Java - você entende mais de strigns do que eu estava achando por essa resposta.  

Mas então: mesmo que o Python possa "adivinhar" alguma codificação (ele usa `sys.getdefaultencoding()` para criar um codec automático de arquivos abertos em modo texto) - é uma péssima prática deixar a adivinhação acontecer. E, como você mesmo comentou nas respostas de Java: não é recomendável usar codificações legadas com representação de caractéres limitadas - então não vejo snetido em usar `latin-1`num programa novo que não tenha que trocar dados com legado

Comment: @jsbueno Tem toda razão! Acho que vou editar minha resposta para deixar isso mais explícito.